# IntelliJ: why my android.support package isn't recognized?

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea, android-support-library

I'm fairly new to IntelliJ and I can't figure out why IntelliJ can't recognize the support package which is suppose to be under speech. I'm trying to import NotificationCompact, but I can't import android.support... it says cannot resolve symbol 'support'. Yes I have the SDK installed and updated. I have the support folder installed, but IntelliJ doesn't recognize it. Yes, I have tried File-->Invalidate Caches. The target-sdk is 12 - 18. My target is 3.0 and above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not included support package in the project structure: "File->Project Structure == > Modules ==> Dependencies". IDEA uses it's own build scripts and ignores jars from lib directory, unless they included into the project structure.